# Observable to process files in a directory periodically

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I'm trying to generate a sequence of events consisting of file names that are existing files in a directory.

That works well. The code goes like this :

```
Observable.Generate(
                        ExistingFiles(path, filter),
                        Condition(),
                        Iterate(),
                        CreateFileChangedEvent()
                        )

           private static Func<List<string>.Enumerator, FileChangedEvent> CreateFileChangedEvent()
            {
                return enumerator => new FileChangedEvent(enumerator.Current, @"Existing");
            }

            private static Func<List<string>.Enumerator, List<string>.Enumerator> Iterate()
            {
                return enumerator =>
                {
                    enumerator.MoveNext();
                    return enumerator;
                };
            }

            private static List<string>.Enumerator ExistingFiles(string path, string filter)
            {
                List<string>.Enumerator files =
                    Directory.GetFiles(path, filter)
                    .ToList()
                    .GetEnumerator();
                // Advance the enumerator to the first result
                files.MoveNext();

                return files;
            }

            private static Func<List<string>.Enumerator, bool> Condition()
            {
                return enumerator => enumerator.Current != null;
            }
        }
```

I would like to wrap this observable in another observable that would trigger file enumeration on a time basis.
All my attempts with Repeat/Replay do not trigger file search and generate the previous events, which is not what I want.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT 1** :
Well, the code could be simplified using ToObservable()

```
Directory.GetFiles(path, filter)
    .ToObservable()
    .Select(s => new FileChangedEvent(s, @"Existing"))
```

Comment: It seems that most of the code deals with converting an IEnumerable<T> into an IObservable<T>. Is there any reason for not using the appropriate ToObservable extension method for IEnumerables ?

Comment: No. I'll start with that.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you want to have your file searching ran on an [interval](http://www.introtorx.com/content/v1.0.10621.0/04_CreatingObservableSequences.html) you could do something like:

```
  Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2))
    .Select(_ => 
      Directory.GetFiles(path, filter)
     .ToObservable()
     .Select(s => new FileChangedEvent(s, @"Existing"))
   )
   .SelectMany(_ => _)
   .Subscribe(onNewFileChangedEvent => {
     Console.WriteLine(onNewFileChangedEvent.ToString());
   });
```

But this would yield the same 'existing' file changed events which you need to de-duplicate before emitting them to your subscription (i guess?). You could play around with the [Buffer operator](http://www.introtorx.com/content/v1.0.10621.0/13_TimeShiftedSequences.html#OverlappingBuffers) to create a diff of two sets of files and emit only those.

### Why the SelectMany()

The original stream returns timer events from the `Interval`. On every event we are returning a new stream of `FileChangedEvents`.

```
   t1--t2--t3
   \    \   \
    \     \   ---t3{evt1,evt2,evt3}
     \      ---t{evt1,evt2,evt3}
      ---t1{evt1,evt2,evt3}
```

Because we want to melt those back into one stream which our subscribers can consume we have to merge these results. Enter `SelectMany()` which combines projection and flattening into a single step. Because we are not We are not interested in the `projection` property of `selectMany` we indicate that we will do nothing to the items as indicated (byconvention) with the `_ => _` underscored syntax.

### Can't I just use the Merge() operator?

`Merge()` is essentially the semantic equivalent of an identity `SelectMany(_ => _)` (there are overloads that do interesting things like control concurrency). There is certainly no issue with the continuous production of sequences to merge. Here is the [original implementation](http://rx.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Rx.NET/Source/System.Reactive.Linq/Reactive/Linq/Observable/Merge.cs)

Comment: Taken as is it works, and, as you say, emit duplicates for each file in the directory. Could you elaborate on the SelectMany() ?

Comment: You can just use `.Merge()` instead of `.SelectMany(_ => _)`

Comment: I'm now using Distinct() to filter out already generated events. No more duplicates.

Comment: Added some elaboration about the SelectMany() vs Merge().

Comment: @Mark `Merge()` is essentially the semantic equivalent of an identity `SelectMany(_ => _)` (there are overloads that do interesting things like control concurrency). There is certainly no issue with the continuous production of sequences to merge. Here is the original implementation: http://rx.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Rx.NET/Source/System.Reactive.Linq/Reactive/Linq/Observable/Merge.cs

Comment: @Mark In fact, as far as I can tell, the documentation you have cited doesn't make a reference to any such limitation either - in fact it explicitly discusses the use of a stream of streams as a source *"...or even an Observable that emits Observables..."*

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! I corrected my answer with your comments.